# Java synchronized - am I doing it right?

Tags: java, asynchronous

I'm not used to working with synchronized. Does the following snippet look right?

```
public void setNewSessionListener(NewSessionListener newSessionListener) {
    if (this.newSessionListener != null)
        synchronized (this.newSessionListener) {
            this.newSessionListener = newSessionListener;
        }
    else
        this.newSessionListener = newSessionListener;
}
```

More specifically do I need to perform a null check? I have a gut feeling there is something fundamentally wrong with that code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two mistakes. The first one is that if you access a field which requires synchronization, you always have to access it with the same lock held. Also you have to check if the field is null and write to the field in the same sychronized block, because otherwise when you write something to the field, it may already be not null.

The second one is that it is best to sychronize on something that doesn't change, in other words, on a static final field or on the instance itself. For example, you can create a lock object specifically for this purpose:

```
private static final Object LOCK = new Object();
```

And then you will write:

```
synchronized (LOCK) {
    if (this.newSessionListener == null) this.newSessionListener = newSessionListener;
}
```

Comment: After reading your post this seems very obvious. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: For this case why not synchronize on the class?

Comment: Synchronizing on a `static` field is not at all the same as synchronizing on `this`.

Comment: @DavidThielen Actually the simplest way is to synchronize on the instance. It doesn't even require anything besides the `synchronized` keyword among the method modifiers. Only in this case it is kind of not visual enough to illustrate what is done. By the way, sometimes you want to hide your lock so no one outside your class can use it for something you didn't intend.

Comment: @PéterTörök Depends on the purpose of synchronization. If it is there only to provide thread-safety, then any of the methods is fine.

Comment: I'll just synchronize on the instance. It's a singleton class so in this case there is no difference between a static final lock and the this reference other than a extra object.

Answer (score 2):

Your feeling is right. You should do the null check inside the `synchronized` block. Otherwise the block won't prevent double initialization. Furthermore, you shouldn't synchronize on `this.newSessionListener` which you are about to change - choose an object (reference) which is going to stay around for the whole scope of the block. This is the only way to guarantee that only one thread can enter this block of code at any point in time. The typical way to achieve this is to `synchronize` on `this`. Alternatively, you may synchronize on a `private final` object, kept for this sole purpose.

Moreover, ultimately you are performing the same assignment in both the `if` and the `else` branches, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: actually if i synchronize on `this` I don't need to preform any null check. The null check was to prevent synchronization on a null object

Comment: @bughi, indeed it is not needed. But this was a harmless minor issue compared to the others, so I didn't bother to mention it :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is, at a minimum, a very bad idea. You are synchronizing on an object you then assign to.

Because you are using synchronized I assume this is called asynchronously and it could be called by one thread while another thread is inside this code. If so, you are not locking on a common object, you are locking on the value it is holding at that point in time.

Probably, and I stress probably, you can do synchronized (this). That will insure that all calls to this method for this specific object are synchronized. And that calls to other instances of this class are locked for that other object - but not across instances.

If you want to synchronize across all instantiated objects, call synchronized (YourClass)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another possibility (i tend to prefer explicit locks over the synchronized block):

```
private ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

lock.lock();
try {
  // do your synchronized code here. 
}
finally {
  lock.unlock();
}
```

Though just by looking at your code, i'm not sure why there's even an if block.  Why are you synchronized in one case, and not the other?  Especially considering you're making the same assignment in either case?

Comment: because in the else case `newSessionListener` was null